# Using a sub domain on my local machine without specifying the port

Tags: xampp

I have a domain that I purchased from my web host. I want to use the subdomain that I have created on my local machine as the files that I am using cannot be installed on the host.

As of right now the subdomain works, however I have to include the port at the end in order to view the site/files that I want. I am hosting statping in case my host were to go down the status page is still up. I am hosting statping on a Windows 10 machine, statping has its own HTTP server. I am using XAMPP.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It sounds like you want to use Apache (in XAMPP) as a [reverse proxy](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Reverse_proxy) for [Statping](https://github.com/statping/statping).

In short, you need an Apache virtual host similar to the following:

```
<VirtualHost *:80>

ServerName subdomain.example.com

ProxyPass / http://host:port/
ProxyPassReverse / http://host:port/

</VirtualHost>
```

Where:

- `subdomain.example.com` is your subdomain.
- `host:port` is either the domain name or IP of the Statping host, along with the port Statping is running on.

### Notes

- If Statping is running on the same local host as Apache (XAMPP), you can simply use `127.0.0.1` or the local IP of the host for the `host` value.
- For `ProxyPass` and `ProxyPassReverse` to work correctly, you need `mod_proxy` enabled in Apache. You will also likely want/need to enable `mod_proxy_html`, `mod_proxy_http` and `mod_proxy_http2` as well. Particularly, enabling `mod_proxy_http2` can avoid a potential (minor) proxy error after completing the Statping setup. These should all be in your main Apache configuration (e.g. `httpd.conf`):

  ```
  ....
  LoadModule proxy_module modules/mod_proxy.so
  ....
  ....
  LoadModule proxy_html_module modules/mod_proxy_html.so
  LoadModule proxy_http_module modules/mod_proxy_http.so
  LoadModule proxy_http2_module modules/mod_proxy_http2.so
  ....
  ```
- When using a reverse proxy, Statping seems to work best at the root of a subdomain (due to how it forms URLs). So if you need to run a second instance of Statping on the same machine, you should use a second subdomain.

---

> When attempting to access `phpmyadmin` on the same network, it redirects to Statping with the error "page does not exist".

If the virtual host entry above is your only virtual host, Apache will forward all requests to that host. More generally, if a host is requested that Apache is "unaware" of, it will redirect requests to the first defined virtual host. Obviously this is an issue if e.g. Statping is not aware of the URL it is being asked to serve.

You can get around this by defining another virtual host ahead of the one listed above to act as a "default" host which won't block access to e.g. `phpmyadmin`:

```
<VirtualHost *:80>

ServerName localhost
DocumentRoot "C:/path/to/xampp/htdocs/"

Redirect permanent /subdomain http://host:port

</VirtualHost>


<VirtualHost *:80>

ServerName subdomain.example.com

ProxyPass / http://host:port/
ProxyPassReverse / http://host:port/

</VirtualHost>
```

**Additional Notes**

- The first virtual host above should work for `localhost`, `127.0.0.1` and whatever the local IP of the PC is (ex. `192.168.1.x`).
- One slight caveat to having a "default" virtual host similar to the one above is that it could be (potentially) served to someone connecting to e.g. `subdomain.example.com` (assuming a hostname error occurred with Apache).
- In the example above, `Redirect permanent /subdomain` is an optional shortcut to the `host:port` combination running Statping. This means you can type e.g. `192.168.1.x/subdomain` and be taken to Statping (`host:port`) locally without actually having to fiddle with your `hosts` file or local DNS.
- `Redirect permanent /subdomain` will show the port in the address bar, just as if you had typed `host:port` manually into the browser.
- Unlike the `ProxyPass` directives given for `subdomain.example.com`, if `Redirect permanent /subdomain` uses a local address, it would only be available locally. However, you can use a public IP or (sub)domain name as well.

Comment: This works however, when attempting to access phpmyadmin on the same network, it redirects to statping with the error "page does not exist".

Comment: How are you accessing `phpMyAdmin` (i.e. what are you typing to get the error you are describing?)

Comment: Internal IP of the machine that it is running on.

Comment: Please see the additional information I have edited in to my original answer. In short, if the example virtual host above is your only virtual host, it's likely you need another "default" host that won't block access to e.g. `phpmyadmin`.

Comment: Thank you, this has worked, can i just copy this code and use it to server my other subdomain on another port also?

Comment: You're welcome. Glad to hear it's working for you. Regarding the additional subdomain, the basic answer should be yes. Just copy the second virtual host, place it below the first two and update the appropriate details. As a small caveat, if you plan to run a virtual host over port 443 (HTTPS), there may be some additional steps. Otherwise, cut and paste should work pretty flawlessly.

Answer (score 0):

Change the port to 80 (HTTP) or 443 (HTTPS). Those are default ports for these protocols, browsers assume them implicitly when none are specified.

Comment: I cant, I have xampp running on port 80. I also need to run two instances of statping.